# 5 letter password either lowercase or uppercase

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given that you can have 5 letter password that contains either lowercase or uppercase. My questions are: 
1) How many possible passwords are there?

I did $52^5 = 380,204,032$ since there are 52 letters, 26 lower and 26 upper.

2) How many possible passwords are lowercase only?

$26^5$ = 11,881,375 since there are only 26 lower

3) How many possible passwords are uppercase only?

$26^5$ = 11,881,375 since there are only 26 upper

4.) How many possible passwords are there that uses at least 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase?

Not sure about this one...

Comment: Total minus the "bad" ones, which have been counted in 2) and 3).

Comment: "At least one upper case" means _not_ "no upper case"--likewise for lower case.  You can make a Venn diagram which shows that _all_ possible passwords (with upper and lower case) includes three disjoint regions: 1) those with _only_ upper case, 2) those with _only_ lower case, and 3) those with _both_ lower case and upper case.

Comment: I have a jar containing $52^5$ marbles that all have either red *or* green swirls (some may have both).  $26^5$ have only red swirls, $26^5$ have only green swirls.  How many have both red and green swirls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you would have to do would be to take the number of possible passwords with uppercase and lowercase combined, then subtract the number of all uppercase and all lowercase combinations.

You would end up with $52^5 - 2*26^5$